# call uv_write from multi thread, its callback never get called

Tags: multithreading, libuv

I've read the tcp-echo-server.c example from libuv, now I'm writing a small multi-thread tcp server based on that.

I used the `uv_default_loop` in the main thread to accept connections, and put new connection into a list.

```
// main thread
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", DEFAULT_PORT, &addr);

    uv_tcp_bind(&server, (const struct sockaddr*)&addr, 0);
    int r = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*) &server, DEFAULT_BACKLOG, OnConnectionCallback);
    if (r)
    {
        ERROR("Listen error %s", uv_strerror(r));
        return;
    }
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
```

and in the second thread, I broadcast a message to all connections I've got.

```
// second thread

    write_req_t *req = (write_req_t*) malloc(sizeof(write_req_t));
    req->buf = uv_buf_init((char *)buffer->data(), buffer->size());
    int r = uv_write((uv_write_t*) req, (uv_stream_t *)this->uv, &req->buf, 1, write_callback);
    if (r)
    {
        ERROR("uv_write error: %s", uv_strerror(ret));
    }
```

accepting connection works, reading from client works, but the writing part didn't work. no error code reported, but it's callback never got triggered.

I went through the doc, unable to find any clue yet. What did I miss?

by the way, I'm using `std::thread`, not the thread api from libuv.

Comment: `libuv` is not thread-safe apart from `uv_async`. Therefore what what you are trying to do is unsafe and will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: So if the `ur_write` api is not thread safe, what's the best practice in my scenario? if the other thread produces some data want to sent to the client, should I hand over data from all other thread to the main thread, then main thread performs the actual sending?

Comment: Yes, you can hand over the data via a thread-safe datastructure to the main thread, `uv_async` to wake it up and sent it there.

Answer (score 2):

libuv is not thread safe thus you need to always access the loop from the same thread where it is running.  If you want to push something from another thread you need to use `uv_async_send` function as follows.

```
uv_loop_t loop;
uv_async_t async;
...
uv_async_init(loop, &async, [](uv_async_t* handle) {
  ...
  // call uv_write or any uv functions
});
uv_async_send(async);
```